# How to updated a column value, with the help of selected row rows in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mariadb

*I'm new to MariaDB.*

*I've a table. Each rows has its own validity.*

```
CREATE TABLE `tariff_table` (
  `transportation_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transporter` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `valid_upto` date NOT NULL,
  `expired_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`transportation_id`)
  )
```

**Table Result :**

```
tariff_id || transporter || valid_upto || expired_status || status   
------------------------------------------------------------------
1         || Raj         || 2014-12-08 ||             0  ||     0
2         || Ram         || 2015-01-10 ||             0  ||     0
3         || Mani        || 2014-03-06 ||             0  ||     0
4         || Mano        || 2015-04-15 ||             0  ||     0
```

*My Requirement is, how can i update the expired status using the select query.*

```
select tariff_id from tariff_table where valid_upto <= DATE(now());
```

Select Query return 2 rows.

```
tariff_id
---------
1
3
```

*With the help of **id**, i need to update as like as below.*

**I Need the below result.**

```
tariff_id || transporter || valid_upto || expired_status || status   
------------------------------------------------------------------
1         || Raj         || 2014-12-08 ||             1  ||     0
3         || Mani        || 2014-03-06 ||             1  ||     0
```

*Help Me.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the `UPDATE` statement, like this:

```
UPDATE `tariff_table`
SET `expired_status` = 1
WHERE valid_upto <= DATE(now());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN` keyword.

```
UPDATE tariff_table SET expired_status = 1 WHERE tariff_id 
IN(select tariff_id from tariff_table where valid_upto <= DATE(now()))
```

OR

```
UPDATE tariff_table SET expired_status = 1 WHERE valid_upto <= DATE(now())
```